# Reject in response to event during unrelated await in async function

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

What is the 'preferred' way to reject an async function when a event fires while within the function?

I am currently doing that by wrapping every async action with `Promise.race`:

```
async function exampleFunction(emitter){
    let lastError;
    emitter.once('error',error=>lastError=error);
    function createCancellable(promise){
        //cancel if any error occurred in between
        if(lastError)throw new Error(lastError);

        //race between the promise, and the next error occurring
        let _callback;
        return Promise.race([
            promise,
            new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
                emitter.on('error', _callback = reject);
            }),
        ]).finally(() => {
            //cleanup
            if (_callback)
                emitter.removeListener('error', _callback);
        });
    }

    //actual code
    await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction());
    await createCancellable(anotherAsyncFunction());
}
```

Is there a better/more concise way to do this?

Comment: So the issue is that you may be paused waiting for `someAsyncFunction` and then you receive the even ton the eventemitter, and you want to reject `exampleFunction`'s promise without waiting for `someAsyncFunction`'s promise to settle?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yes that is my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's any other way to do what you've said you want, since fundamentally you *do* need a race between two promises at each stage (the eventemitter's error, and what you're actually doing).

But it can be a lot simpler, which may make it more palatable:

```
async function exampleFunction(emitter){
    const pError = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        emitter.once('error', reject);
    });
    const createCancellable = promise => Promise.race([pError, promise]);

    await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction());
    await createCancellable(anotherAsyncFunction());
}
```

It's tempting to wrap all of the logic (the calls to `someAsyncFunction` and `anotherAsyncFunction`) in a single `async` function and then race that with the error, but nothing would stop that new wrapper from continuing to completion when the error occurred. So your approach of individual races makes sense.

---

Re your comment:

> This catches any error that gets queued while sychronous code runs right?

It does as of the next `await`, which may not be early enough for you. Let's add some synchronous code:

```
async function exampleFunction(emitter){
    // Start synchronous block 0
    const pError = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        emitter.once('error', reject);
    });
    const createCancellable = promise => Promise.race([pError, promise]);

    // End synchronous block 0
    await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction());
    // Start synchronous block 1
    doThis();            // All of these are synchronous, starting
    doThat();            // after `someAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves
    doSomethingElse();   // and before we call `anotherAsyncFunction`
    // End synchronous block 1
    await createCancellable(anotherAsyncFunction());
    // Start synchronous block 2
    doYetAnotherThing(); // This is synchronous again, starting after
    keepDoingStuff();    // `anotherAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves and
    okayLastThingNow();  // continuing until the end of the function
    // End synchronous block 2
}
```

Two scenarios:

1. The eventemitter's error occurs *during* `someAyncFunction`'s processing, while it's waiting for something else to complete. The job to call the eventemitter's event callback gets run, rejecting `pError`. That immediately rejects the `Promise.race` and rejects the `exampelFunction` promise; no code after that `await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction());` line runs.
2. The eventemitter's error occurs *after* `someAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves, while "Synchronous block 1" is running. In that case, the synchronous block will continue because synchronous jobs cannot be interrupted to do something else, so the callback from the eventemitter is put in the job queue. Then when you do `await`, the current job ends and other jobs can be run. If the eventemitter's event callback runs, it rejects that promise, and so `exampleFunction` rejects as of the next `await` — **but**, `anotherAsyncFunction` **does** get called and started, because that happens before the call to `Promise.race`. If you want to avoid triggering `anotherAsyncFunction`, you'll need to insert another `await`, see `***` comment:

   ```
   async function exampleFunction(emitter){
       // Start synchronous block 0
       const pError = new Promise((_, reject) => {
           emitter.once('error', reject);
       });
       const createCancellable = promise => Promise.race([pError, promise]);

       // End synchronous block 0
       await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction());
       // Start synchronous block 1
       doThis();            // All of these are synchronous, starting
       doThat();            // after `someAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves
       doSomethingElse();   // and before we call `anotherAsyncFunction`
       // End synchronous block 1
       await createCancellable(Promise.resolve()); // ***
       await createCancellable(anotherAsyncFunction());
       // Start synchronous block 2
       doYetAnotherThing(); // This is synchronous again, starting after
       keepDoingStuff();    // `anotherAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves and
       okayLastThingNow();  // continuing until the end of the function
       // End synchronous block 2
   }
   ```

To handle #2 more simply, you could pass `createCancellable` a callback to call, something like this:

```
async function exampleFunction(emitter){
    // Start synchronous block 0
    const pError = new Promise((_, reject) => {
        emitter.once('error', reject);
    });
    const createCancellable = (callback, ...args) => {
        return Promise.race([pError, Promise.resolve()])
            .then(() => Promise.race([pError, callback(...args)]));
    };

    // End synchronous block 0
    await createCancellable(someAsyncFunction); // *** no ()
    // Start synchronous block 1
    doThis();            // All of these are synchronous, starting
    doThat();            // after `someAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves
    doSomethingElse();   // and before we call `anotherAsyncFunction`
    // End synchronous block 1
    await createCancellable(anotherAsyncFunction); // *** no ()
    // Start synchronous block 2
    doYetAnotherThing(); // This is synchronous again, starting after
    keepDoingStuff();    // `anotherAsyncFunction`'s promise resolves and
    okayLastThingNow();  // continuing until the end of the function
    // End synchronous block 2
}
```

Notice we don't *call* `someAsyncFunction` or `anotherAsyncFunction`, we just pass the functions to `createCancellable` and let it call them after first checking for eventemitter's rejection.

So maybe that isn't simpler than just throwing in `await createCancellable(Promise.resolve());`. :-)

Comment: I guess i was overthinking it by a lot. This catches any error that gets queued while sychronous code runs right?

Comment: @sunny-lan - I don't think you were overthinking it. And your question raises an issue, so I'm updating the answer.

Comment: @sunny-lan can you give an example of a `someAsyncFunction` and the `emitter` where the error is fired synchronously, and what exactly the expected behaviour is?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder would something like this work? `asyncFunc=>pError.then(()=>Promise.race([pError, asyncFunc()]))` Since if pError is rejected the race and asyncFunc will not be run?

Comment: @sunny-lan - No, because `pError` never resolves, so the `then` handler never runs.

Comment: @sunny-lan - Thanks for fixing those typos! :-) Sorry about that.